# How to get the specified value using regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get the `120/90` value using regex.Can anyone please help me to get the value based on the resting hp string?

Example:

Resting BP(mmHg): 120/90

Thanks

Comment: 120/90 does not exitst in your test string... Also, what is the logic to get the value?

Comment: Sry it is 120/90.i have pdf document which contains this line. To get the bp value i will read the entire line of the pdf document. Suppose if the line contains resting hp ,i need to get the alphanumneric value next to this string.Thats all

Comment: What have you tried?  If you post your code and explain what it does then we can help fix it, but as it stands you're just asking someone to write your code.  Otherwise, go to https://regex101.com/ put your line of text in the bottom textbox and work out the regular expression that works in the top textbox.

Comment: Suppose if i try this below regex i am not getting the remaining part (90) after slash.var pattern = @"(?<Pre>[^-]+):(?<Post>.+)";
               var mtch = Regex.Match(input1, pattern);
                Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", mtch.Groups["Post"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `BP[^:]+:\s*(\d+\/\d+)`

Explanation:

`BP` - match `BP` literally

`[^:]+` - match one or more of characters other than `:`

`:` - match `:` literally

`\s*` - match zero or more of whitespaces

`(\d+\/\d+)` - match one or more digits, `/` literally, and again one or more digits and store it insida first capturing groups - this will be your disred result

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9NAiV/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using following you can get all the values at one time and put into a dictionary.  The code splits around the colon :

```
           string input = "Resting HR(bpm): 62 Resting BP(mmHg): 120/90 MaxPER: 60 Target HR(Nun): 180";
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^\s]+):\s+(?'value'[^\s]+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> measurement in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Measurement : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", measurement.Key, measurement.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```